# MessageDrivenBean unable to validate user on remote server

Tags: java, jms, wildfly

I'm trying to listen to a JMS queue on a remote Wildfly server. I have successfully connected to the remote to send a message with the same user, but when I setup my MessageDrivenBean I get an error.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageListenerBean", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "username"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "p@ssw0rd!"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "/queue/receive"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="connectionParameters", propertyValue = "host=localhost;port=8080")})
public class MessageListenerBean implements MessageListener {
```

The error is

```
AMQ222216: Security problem while creating session: 
AMQ119031: Unable to validate user from invm:0. 
Username: username; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
```

I am assuming my configuration is incorrect, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the proper `connectorClassName` on your activation configuration. The default is `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory` which is why it's using an invm connector to the local broker. Use this:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="connectorClassName", propertyValue = "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory")
```